Build a Neural Network for Multi-output Regression
I have a network model that accepts about 25 inputs and outputs 3 actions.
The outputs are: delta X and delta Y of the robot and the angle of the robot.
After I enter the data into the model, I get very different (and strange) predictions for the angle
What could be the reason for this? And how can it be fixed? If someone can attach a patch (or another model) it will help me a lot! :)
Here are some details:
Unique values in the first column of Y: [-65. -45.   0.  10.  15.  25.  35.  45.  65.  90. 115. 135. 155. 180.
225. 245. 250. 270.]
angle Labels: tensor([  0., 270., 270.,   0.,   0.,   0., 180., 180., 270.,   0.,  90.,   0.,
270.,   0.,  90.,  90.,   0.,  90.,  90.,   0.,   0.,  90.,  90.,   0.,
270., 270.,   0., 270., 270., 270.,   0., 180.,  90., 180.,   0.,  90.,
0., 270.,   0., 180.,  90., 180.,   0.,  90., 180., 180., 180.,  90.,
0., 180.,   0., 270., 270.,  90., 180., 180.,   0.,   0.,  90., 180.,
270.,  90.,  90.,   0.])
angle Outputs(prediction): tensor([ 58.0496, 134.1157,  86.4644,  38.5840, 207.9981,  45.4016, 145.8846,
95.8378,  85.2003, 149.1076, 138.2106, 194.3036,  38.5840,  76.8651,
57.8443, 109.1870,  45.4016, 146.5283,  40.7307])
This is my model:
# Define the neural network model
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, num_actions):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 64*2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(64*2, 32*2)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(32*2, num_actions) 

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.output_layer(out)

        return out

Thank you so much!

I see four potential solutions for you:

think through your data - are all necessary input variable included? is output in the most convenient form to model? Maybe it should be in radians and not degrees?
change your output - it's the simplest solution and I would try normalizing the output first. Such a model might struggle with outputs with different distributions.
add more layers - it might help if the modelled relation is complicated. If you add more layers, you can consider BatchNormalization (I would add it even now before the first layer as an alternative to normalize it before the model). Sometimes it's also helpful to add an activation function which looks similar to the relation you work on.
change your network architecture - you can try to split your last layer(s) into three separate branches to let the model process these pieces of information distinctly. It helped me a lot during one project.


My problem is with reference to the data (even before the split into a training and test set)
I converted the angle to radians and then to 2 columns of sin, cos
Still the prediction is not good.
How would you treat angle data?

@May I don't know what is the core issue, but I mentioned different plausible approaches you can try to solve it. I think you can try focusing on the combination of point 0 and point 2 and try to make the output activation function compatible with the output. For instance - you can try using 180*tanh on output or some trigonometric function like atan.
